# angular - know when template rendering is finished - with async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a progress guage component to show the loading process of the template components which are rendered with async pipe.

Question is how do I know the rendering (with async pipe) is finished for a given component.

Comment: You can try to make use of component lifecycle hooks i think.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks do any of those help you?

Comment: I tried lifecycle, it turns out `ngAfterViewInit` is triggered before async pipe coming back

Comment: do you need to know it for the template or for the component ?

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I need to know it for all components in the template, so I can update the loading progress gauge

Comment: as there might be multiple async pipe in the template and you want to update the loading progress gauge once they are all completed?

Comment: @GérômeGrignon yes, I want to update the progress gauge once all async pipe finished (success or failure)

Answer (score 4):

Use *forkJoin* rxjs operator to wrap your observable sources together. You'll get the response when the last value is received :

```js
forkObservable$ = forkJoin({
    obs1: this.observable1$,
    obs2: this.observable2$,
    obs3: this.observable3$,
  });
```

This way you can display your gauge until the last emitted value is received (gauge being a simple value displayed for the example :

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="forkObservable$ | async as forkObservable; else loading">
 <app-comp1>{{forkObservable.obs1}}</app-comp1>
 <app-comp2>{{forkObservable.obs2}}</app-comp2>
 <app-comp3>{{forkObservable.obs3}}</app-comp3>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  loading {{dataLoaded}} / 3
</ng-template>
```

To update the value of the gauge (or 'dataLoaded' for the example), you can use the *tap* rxjs operator on each observable in order to update its value :

```js
observable1$ = of('CyberTruck').pipe(
    tap(() => this.dataLoaded++)
  );
```

[Here is a working example with Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sample-forkjoin-loading?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) using a delay on each observable in order to simulate the asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Give you a thumb up! However still not exactly what I want. I need the component to be rendered immediately when it's corresponding async pipe is finished. Your solution disabled all components until all pipe finished.

Comment: You mean the gauge is just a piece of ui and not a placeholder for the components as a loading indicator ? If so, just use the last part of my answer using the tap operator and place each observable on each component using ngIf. When the data is loaded, the component will be rendered  and the gauge counter will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need loading progress before data rendered.
`*ngIf="obs$ | async as obs; else loading"`

Comment: No this is not what I want. Let's say I have three components in the template, all of them has async pipe, then I will init a loading progressing gauge with 3, for each one of the component's async pipe finished, I will increment the progress by 1, until all three component loading finished, that is 3 of 3 done